# Menu-Flickering from Dropdown (position absolute, visible after hover)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

i have a menu-flicker-problem and spend 3 hours investigating where this flicker is coming from - but i can't solve it.

hover over the point "Career" and navigate with the mouse to the dropdownmenu to see the flickering.

my current browser: Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m but also happens in Firefox - but not that "hard" like in Chrome.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amwkgtue/

i know why the fiddle is not working correctly: you have to expand the preview-window so the nav is actually floating (it has min-width: 1440px) - or go full fullscreen: https://fiddle.jshell.net/amwkgtue/show/

```
<header>
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="bluegradient">
      <div class="container navigation">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <nav class="nav" id="navigation">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Places</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#">Career</a>
                  <div class="childcontainer">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <ul class="child row">
                            <li class="col-sm-4 parent"><a href="#">Example</a>
                              <ul class="child">
                                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                              </ul>
                              <a href="#" class="hidden-md hidden-lg navcaret"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="socialbar col-sm-12">
                          <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li>
                              <a href="#"><img src="typo3conf/ext/sitetemplate/Resources/Public/img/facebook.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#"><img src="typo3conf/ext/sitetemplate/Resources/Public/img/linkedin.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#"><img src="typo3conf/ext/sitetemplate/Resources/Public/img/youtube.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="hidden-md hidden-lg navcaret"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                  <a href="#" class="hidden-md hidden-lg navcaret"></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

don't mind the missing images, they are not necessary to reproduce the flicker.

scss:

```
/* COLORS */

$primary: #24366e; // BLUE
$yellow: #ffed00; // YELLOW
$grey: #f3f7fb;
$font: "Swiss-Thin",
Arial,
sans-serif;
$font-light: "Swiss-Light",
Arial,
sans-serif;
$font-medium: "Swiss-Medium",
Arial,
sans-serif;
$fontmedium: 500;
////////////
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: $font;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.48;
}

a,
button,
.btn,
.btn-small {
  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    outline: 0;
  }
}

.container,
.container-fluid,
.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-right: 4%;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -4%;
  margin-right: -4%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container,
  .container-fluid,
  .col-xs-1,
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-md-1,
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-xs-2,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-xs-3,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-xs-4,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-xs-5,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-xs-6,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-xs-7,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-xs-8,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-xs-9,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-xs-10,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-xs-11,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-xs-12,
  .col-sm-12,
  .col-md-12,
  .col-lg-12 {
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
  }
  .row {
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-right: -35px;
  }
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

$transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
header .fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 121px;
  max-height: 121px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: $transition;
  &.affix {
    transition: $transition;
    max-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header .fixed {
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    &.affix {
      height: 140px;
      max-height: 140px;
    }
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  header .fixed {
    height: 248px;
    max-height: 248px;
    transition: $transition;
    &.affix {
      height: 148px;
      max-height: 148px;
      transition: $transition;
    }
  }
}

.fixed {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.bluegradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(36, 54, 110, 1) 0%, rgba(36, 54, 110, 1) 38%, rgba(36, 54, 110, 0.35) 100%);
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  div[class^='col-'] {
    position: static;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .mobilemenu {
    display: none;
    z-index: -20;
  }
  .navigation {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 65px;
  }
  #navigation {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #navigation .col-sm-12 {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .fixed.affix .navigation #navigation {
    padding-top: 4px;
    -webkit-padding-before: 5px;
    ul {
      li {
        a {
          @media (max-width: 1280px) {
            padding: 10px 12px !important;
          }
          padding: 10px 25px !important;
        }
        &.parent:hover {
          >.childcontainer {
            padding-top: 148px !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .fixed .navigation #navigation {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 195px;
    -webkit-padding-before: 196px;
    text-align: center;
    ul {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      li {
        float: left;
        position: static;
        a {
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 18px;
          font-family: $font-light;
          transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          @media (max-width: 1280px) {
            padding: 13px 12px !important;
          }
          padding: 13px 25px;
          &:hover,
          &:focus {
            background-color: $primary;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: $yellow;
            transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
          }
        }
        .childcontainer {
          visibility: hidden;
          opacity: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #fff;
          left: 0;
          z-index: -1;
        }
        >.childcontainer>.container-fluid {
          background-color: $primary;
          visibility: hidden;
          opacity: 0;
          min-height: 51px;
          max-height: 52px;
          transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
          ul.list-inline {
            display: none;
          }
        }
        ul.child {
          display: none;
          ul.child {
            display: none;
          }
        }
        &.parent:hover,
        &.parent:focus {
          >a {
            color: $yellow;
            background-color: $primary;
          }
          >.childcontainer {
            display: block;
            visibility: visible;
            background-color: #fff;
            opacity: 1;
            top: 0;
            padding-top: 248px;
            transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
          }
          >.childcontainer>.container {
            min-height: 92px;
          }
          >.childcontainer>.container>.row>.col-sm-12>ul.child {
            display: block;
            list-style-type: none;
            width: 100%;
            /*@-moz-document url-prefix() {
                            left: 1px;
                        }*/
            >li>a {
              padding: 10px 25px;
              display: block;
              background-image: none;
              background-size: auto 24px;
              background-position: left -1px center;
              color: $primary;
            }
            >li:hover>a,
            >li.active>a,
            >li:focus>a {
              background-image: url(../img/arrow_blue.png);
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: auto 24px;
              background-color: #fff;
            }
            li.parent:hover {
              >ul.child {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                left: 100%;
                margin-top: -43px;
                border-left: 1px solid #fff;
              }
            }
          }
          >.childcontainer>.container-fluid {
            background-color: $primary;
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
            .socialbar {
              text-align: right;
              padding-top: 10px;
              padding-bottom: 5px;
              ul>li>a {
                background-color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit;
                transition: none;
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 0;
                &:hover,
                &:focus {
                  transition: none;
                  color: inherit;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  background-color: inherit;
                }
              }
            }
            ul.list-inline {
              display: inline-block;
              li {
                display: inline-block !important;
                margin-right: 15px;
                &:last-of-type {
                  margin-right: 0px;
                }
                img {
                  max-width: 30px;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        &.active {
          >a {
            color: $yellow;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  .fixed .navigation #navigation {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 26px;
    -webkit-padding-before: 27px;
    text-align: center;
    ul {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
  .navigation {
    width: 1370px !important;
  }
  #navigation {
    padding-top: 21px;
    -webkit-padding-before: 22px;
  }
}
```

ah forgot to mention this:

this navigation was a `<ul class="nav nav-justified">` before, and at that time the dropdown was working smoothly!

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work, if it's a bootstrap template, try using bootply.  Then all you need to do is add the extra styles so we can see what styles you are applying (rather than having top search through all the bootstrap styles as well)

Comment: uhm. for me it's working on Chrome?! i don't know why it shouldn't work? i added the bootstrap-cdn js/css even if i have a complete personalized bootstrap version for this project, but the effect/mistake happens with default-bootstrap as well. but you are right as well, i could have left out the col-stuff css i made especially for different viewports.

Comment: i know why the fiddle is not working correctly: you have to expand the preview-window so the nav is actually floating (it has min-width: 1440px) - or go full fullscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did a workaround because i couldn't find the flickering issue in floating points - so switched to inline-block list elements again instead of floating list-elements.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you are using many of the Bootstrap classes for the header. Also, you have a "nav" nested within another "nav", which is causing styling issues.

Here is a very simple Bootstrap header with a hover dropdown:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Places</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Career <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Make dropdown show on hover, rather than click (Only on desktop viewports) */
  ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/charliebeckstrand/pen/YWaaWp

Comment: i don't need a "bootstrap"-nav i'm using bootstrap on that site simply for accordion, grid-system and affix. my bootstrap-version on server is configured for my needs - i just added the cdn-version from bootstrap itself because it makes no real difference on the "mistake" which happens. 

and also it's not wanted that the dropdown just "shows" with display: block, it's wanted that it moves down with the sliding animation.

Comment: and btw: ".nav" does only this: `margin-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0;` and `list-style: none;`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your issue due to the fiddle being broken on the smaller viewport. I'm taking a look at it now.